# Determining XY location

Tags: coordinates, convert, geolocation, xy

I am new to a system and the information it gives me for job sites is 
XY(238391648,71539666):294616358697.
I have been trying to use convertors to change this to a longitude and latitude definition but no luck. I am in Michigan.

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify first which coordinate system those coordinates are represented into or projected to. This [URL](http://gis.mtu.edu/?p=117) I explains in more details Michigan Coordinate Systems. Once you get that figured out then you could convert your coordinates into Lat Long, or WGS84.

Could you also state which software you are using for the task?